# How to make font size resize automatically to fit in a text box in photoshop using script

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dui ante, euismod id quam eu. "
}
```

I have 6 different Photoshop file (.psd) with completely different template and design.

Each psd file have a paragraph text box of size say

1. 600px X 600px
2. 500px X 500px
3. 400px X 400px

and so on. They all have different sizes of bounding box. (They don't have exact square size as mentioned above.)

I am writing a script which takes the text object from JSON and changes the text content of these paragraph text boxes.

```
// Include the JSON Parser
#include json2js.js

var originalunit = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// function to read json
function loadJson(relpath){
    var script = new File($.fileName);
    var jsonFile = new File(script.path + '/../json/' + relpath);

    jsonFile.open( 'r' );
    var str = jsonFile.read();
    jsonFile.close();

    return JSON.parse(str);
}

// Read the JSON
var json = loadJson( 'test.json' );

var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var layerRef = docRef.artLayers.getByName( 'text' );

layerRef.textItem.contents = json.text;
layerRef.rasterize(RasterizeType.TEXTCONTENTS);

var textHeight = layerRef.bounds[2] - layerRef.bounds[0];
var boundHeight = layerRef.textItem.height;

var currentFontSize = layerRef.textItem.size;
currentFontSize = currentFontSize.toString().replace(" pt", "");


if(textHeight > boundHeight) {
    fitText(textHeight, boundHeight, currentFontSize, layerRef, json);
 }

//function to fit text inside the  box
function fitText(textHeight, boundHeight, currentFontSize, layerRef, json){
    while(textHeight > boundHeight) {
        currentFontSize--;
        layerRef.textItem.size = currentFontSize;
        layerRef.textItem.contents = json.text;
        textHeight = layerRef.bounds[2] - layerRef.bounds[0];
    }
 }
```

I have set the font-size of text box, so that 15 character can perfectly fit in the box.

But the `text` object can change to any number of character, say 30, 50 or 70 character. Since, the size of the text box and the font size is fixed in the template,

**How can I resize the font-size to automatically fit any number of character within the text box ?**